# increase the timeout of asp.net webservice in the apache and mono context

Tags: asp.net, mono

I want increase the timeout of asp.net webservice in the apache and mono context
but this code is not working:

```
  <sessionState timeout="120"></sessionState>

<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="85000"  />

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps which are there in the below link:

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10111748/how-can-we-increase-the-timeout-of-a-thread-from-webconfig.aspx